# Bridged networking not working in Virtualbox under Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, adapter, windows-10

I just upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and found that I am unable to start Virtualbox VMs configured with a bridged adapter.

See the configuration below:

[image: Virtualbox preferences 1]

[image: Virtualbox preferences 2]

Comment: Virtual box 5.1.8 is working fine in Windows 10

Comment: I resetted all netwerork connections on the computer to see if it resolved an unrelated issue. Hence I thought that the VirtualBox installation might have been affected, so I uninstalled and installed VirtualBox, and the list of bridge adapters was filled again.

Answer (score 62):

First of all you have to create a VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet adapter

In Virtualbox :

- Go to File > Preferences
  On the Network tab select Host only Networks click on "add a Host-only adapter" give it a name by default it is "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet adapter"

In Windows :

- go to Network connections on Windows and highlight both the real adapter and the new virtual ethernet adapter that you just created.
- Right click  and select "Bridge Connections", it's going to create a network bridge in Windows.

Now configure your VM :

- in the Network part you can activate a new adapter and then select Attached to Host only adapter
- Choose the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet adapter you have just created

You can now configure your static IP Address by modifying /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.1.1
```

You can now restart eth0 by doing :

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

Some wireless adapters don't work

Comment: Where you put the ip? In the virtual machine? I can set a IP in the same LAN or I must be set the same IP of the bridge connection?The gateway is the IP address of the router?

Comment: Host Only isn't the same as Bridged Adapter: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html, which does work on Windows 10 Build 14393.351, VirtualBox  5.1.8r111374.

Comment: This method just makes my host machine also unable to reach the internet

Comment: To fix my issue, I only had to create a new Host-only adapter in Virtual Box as described in the first step, then associate it as the second network adapter in the VM settings (VM has to be shutdown first).

Answer (score 48):

Go to your net card. Go to  properties and then `Install` -> `Service`, which? This: VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver

Reopen Virtual Box

Comment: You will need to pick "Have Disk" and browse to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netlwf`

Comment: I got this ... : Could not add the requested feature. The error is: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

Comment: this solution worked for me. i think an update broke my current setup as it was working a month ago then when i launched vbox today, i am unable to select the bridged adapter.

Answer (score 27):

My Windows 10 machine was automagically updated today.  Looks like the "Windows 10 Anniversary update"  When I restarted Virtualbox my server with a bridged adapter showed same as OP.  I tried rerunning the VirtualBox installer (it did a Repair) - that did not fix the issue.  I tried running the installer again as Admin (it did a Repair) - that did not fix.  I ran the installer and selected UnInstall, then ran it again to Install.  And the Network adapter settings looked good.  Server started and connected to my network as usual.  Whew.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I did the exact same thing as you and the adapter is still missing - which brought me here searching and I find you had success - I guess I need a better hammer to beat the software with.

Comment: Exact same story with Virtualbox 6.0.8 after Windows 10 update to v1903 (build 18362.116) Fixed by removing + installing VirtualBox.

Comment: I experienced the same issue - my Win 10 updated to v2004 and evidently removed my VirtualBox ethernet adapters.  Repairing did not work.  I had to uninstall VirtualBox and re-install it (no reboot needed).  This created the ethernet adapters and then I was able to use bridged networking.

Comment: same case, work 100%, because the virtualbox installer have one option in the installer for load your Bridge Connections in ur instalation

Comment: Fоr me also help last step. When I uninstall and reinstalled, the adapter immediately appeared.

Answer (score 13):

Install the latest Virtual box 5.x and this issue will be resolved.

Comment: I'm running the latest version (5.0.26) and I have got this problem.

Comment: This didn't work for 5.1.  check  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32411744/663172)

Comment: Didn't fix mine and it is 2017.

Comment: Does not solve the problem . Running 5.2.0. guest : ubuntu, host : windows

Comment: Upgrading VirtualBox 5.2.0 -> 5.2.4 fixed bridged networking problem for me. In my case guest was simply unable to reach network with all configuration correct.

Answer (score 11):

Uninstall then run the setup program again but this time as Administrator. Make sure the VB bridge driver is selected during installation.

Comment: This is not working, not helping and takes a long time to do.

Comment: This works for my case.
As pointed by this post, https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=56792
this problem is for the lack of "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver", rerun virtual box installer as administrator, and select "Bridged networking driver" during installation, it works now.

Comment: @FlorianNeiss well it worked for me and others. What do you call a long time? Uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox shouldn't take more than about 30m. Compared to time spent troubleshooting and trying some of the other suggestions here that doesn't seem like a "long time" to me!

Comment: @Caltor in my case it took 2 hours plus VB did not regognize my External Drive Z: so I had to reimport all my VB disks. Complete work day ruined. :/

Comment: Confirmed this is the Fix for VirtualBox (recent) version 6.1.26 on Windows 10.

When the installer isn't "Run as Administrator", I can reproduce the problem where "Bridge Adapter" is "Not selected" (after trying several things).

Also, thanks to this YouTube video for the very same fix:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZF4UFe1E54Q

Answer (score 11):

## Windows 11 is not listing a bridged adapter for VirtualBox

Since I've ended up on this old topic from Windows 11 issues, I'm sure others also will, so I wanted to provide an up to date answer for those experiencing this on Windows 11.

This expands on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47418596/349659 and its comments to be more easily digestible and relevant to Windows 11.

### How to add a bridged adapter for Windows 11 and Virtualbox when none are showing

1. Open windows start button.
2. Search for: `network`.
3. Choose: `View network connections` via the control panel.
4. Right click your primary connection (for me it was just Ethernet since I'm on a wired connection).
5. Select: `Properties`.
6. Click: `Install...`.
7. Select: `Service`.
8. Click: `Add...`.
9. Click: `Have Disk...`.
10. Click: `Browse`.
11. Navigate to the associated virtualbox install location for your given drive. For example mine was: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netlwf`.
12. Select the file: `VBoxNetLwf.inf` in the above directory.
13. Click: `OK`.
14. Select: `VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver`.
15. Click: `OK`.

### Select the bridged adapter in VirtualBox

You should now be able to restart VirtualBox, select bridged adapter for your network configuration for your virtual machine, and now names should populate in the *Names* dropdown; select your primary connection and you should be good to go now.

Comment: Also works for Win 10

Answer (score 9):

This is how I mananged to fix this problem:

Enable "Windows 8" compatibility for VirtualBox executable:
right-click on VirtualBox shortcut>Properties: in Properties dialog box: switch to "Compatibility" tab, under "Compatibility mode" section, select the check box next to: "Run this program in compatibility mode", make sure "Windows 8" is selected in combo box. click Ok, run VirtualBox again!
(it's not needed to run as Administrator)

p.s.:  It seems that VirtualBox doesn't yet fully support Windows 10, so some features might not work properly on some computers

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried your solution but without success.

Looking to the official documentation of Virtualbox, it's true that they are a lot of issues with Windows 10

Comment: I tried compatibility mode with Windows 8 to no avail. It is strange, because my bridges networking works sometimes in Windows 10 with VirtualBox (usually after a fresh reboot of host machine and virtual client). I sure hope they get this issue resolved, it is not convenient to have to reboot my PC every time the virtual machine network isn't working properly!

Comment: Disabling "Hyper-V" might also fix some other issues related to running VirtualBox VMs on Windows 10 system, it's because Windows built-in virtualization solution, called Hyper-V, doesn't work well with VirtualBox. (to disable: in Control Panel: Programs and Features>Turn Windows Features on or off: un-check the check mark next to "Hyper-V"

Answer (score 7):

Install "vbox-ssl-cacertificate.crt" certificate from `%userprofile%\\.virtualbox\` and then reboot. If you don't have `.virtualbox` folder - launch "Oracle VM VirtualBox" once and this folder will appear.

I had this issue not only on my machine but on many hosts, and this certificate fixed the issue. I figured it out by chance, because nowhere said about this certificate -_-

Answer (score 4):

From Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/39af75/for_my_win10_companions_heres_how_to_get/

I can't see the original source in this thread, although I would like to.

I am using these instructions with a laptop that upgraded from windows 8 to windows 10. I have to repeat the last instructions after rebooting.

> I have test an get solution for my self and want to share my solution.
>   - Host Only worked
>   - Bridge Adapter worked
>
> My Configuration is
>   - Surface Pro 1
>   - Clean install Windows 10 x64 build 10130
>   - VirtualBox-5.0.0_RC1-100731-Win.exe
>
> (this is my opinion but not tested on how to remove previous version
>   by install VirtualBox-5.0.0_RC1-100731-Win.exe with select all
>   function to install its will fault and rollback all, then its same as
>   uninstall)
>
> Install Step
>   - Right Click on VirtualBox-5.0.0_RC1-100731-Win.exe and select "Run as Administrator"
>   - "Unselect" option bridge network
>
> - next until finish
> - Open "Device Manager", you can use search bar to get this, under "Network adapters"  then Right Click "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet
>     Adapter" select "Update Driver Software" select "Search automactic"
>     wait until its finish
> - Open "Network Connections", you can use search bar to get this, at here you should find VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
> - Open "CMD", you can use search bar to get this, Right Click and Select Run as Administrator
> - cd to your install path and run command "VirtualBox-5.0.0_RC1-100731-Win.exe -extract" its will return pop-up
>     tell where is extracted folder
> - in extracted folder extract "VirtualBox-5.0.0_RC1-r100731-MultiArch_amd64.msi" by 7-Zip or any
>     similar
> - in msi extracted folder rename all files by remove file_ in front of them
> - copy "VBoxNetFltNobj.sys" and "VBoxNetFlt.sys" to C:\Windows\System32\
> - Open "CMD", you can use search bar to get this, Right Click and Select Run as Administrator run command "regsvr32.exe /s
>     VBoxNetFltNobj.sys" run command "regsvr32.exe /s VBoxNetFlt.sys"
> - Open "Network Connections", you can use search bar to get this, Right Click on any real network adapter  select Properties select
>     Install select Service select "Have Disk" and browse to "VBoxDrv.inf"
>     select "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" after finish
>     install you should see its avaliable in this connection
> - On Start Menu Right Click on "Orcle VM VirtualBox" select open file location
> - Right Click on Shortcut then select properties on tab "Compatibility" checked "Run this Program as Administrator"
>
> !!! this very important to run application with adminstrator if not
>   you will lose host-only network adapter
>
> - Open "Virtual Box" select file > preference select network then select Host On Network select edit change ip to 192.168.56.1 and
>     netmask to 255.255.255.0
> - Now you can use both host-only and bridge network on your guest
>
> I think reason why normal installation was error is about
>   Administrator access level when regis service and run application
>
> Sorry for my bad english and this is so long procedure
>
> Hope this will work for you too. ^_^!

Comment: This work for me on windows 2008 r2 ent with virtualbox 5.1.0-108711.  for renaming you can use powershell cmd >> `Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "file_","" }`

Comment: for me it was enough to update the driver of the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter (second bullet point)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with similar way to @Khalil's but I attched to 'Bridged Adapter' instead of 'Host-only Adapter'. [Here](https://gblue1223.wordpress.com/2017/08/16/virtualbox5-1-26s-bridge-mode-on-windows-10/) is more detail with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

My very simple solution that worked: select another networkcard!

1. Make sure your guest is shut down
2. Goto the guest Settings > Network > Adavanced
3. Change the Adapter Type to another adapter.
4. Start your guest and check if you got a decent IP for your network.

If it doesn't work, repeat steps and try yet another network adapter. The very basic PCnet adapters have a high succes-rate.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When using a bridged connection you are bridging the virtual network of the guest (VM) to the physical network device of the host (Windows 10).  The host physical device then assigns the IP address and manages the network connection of the guest OS (VM).

[image]

What you need to check.  On Windows 10 (host), go to Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network Connections, right click the physical device that you are trying to bridge to on your guest OS (VM) and make sure that "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" and "Brdige Driver" are enabled.

[image]

Note:
The bridge connection choice in the guest (VM) VirtualBox settings and the phsyical device name are the same...
Also, you may find that inactive / disabled network devices on the host will not show in the host (windows 10) until you connect to them i.e. ethernet cable to a LAN port.

That should help you solve the bridged connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today after updating the Virtual Box.
Got resolved by uninstalling Virtual Box and moving back to old version V5.2.8

Answer (score 0):

As of now (5.2.20) bug is fixed. The only action required is to download the latest version and bridge mod should function normally.

Answer (score 0):

In Case some one is looking and none of the above resolves your issue :
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90650&p=434965#p434965

placing the WIFI as the first adapter [MTDesktop, AllowALL] and the LAN WIRED [MTServer,AllowAll] as the second adapter.
In the Guest machine I disable the First Adapter in Adapter Settings. I can then ping internal, external whatever.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem.
i updated to new version of VirtualBox 5.2.26
and checked to make sure Bridge Adapter was enabled in the installation process 
now is working

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box gives a lot of issues when it comes to bridge adaptor. I had the same issue with Virtual Box for windows 10. I decided to create VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet adapter. But I again got issues while creating the host-only ethernet adaptor. I decided to switch to **vmware**. Vmware did not give me any issues. After installing vmware (and after changing few settings in the BIOS) and installing ubuntu on it, it automatically connected to my host machine's internet. It was able to generate it's own IP address as well and could also ping the host machine (windows machine). Hence, for me virtual box created a lot of issues whereas, vmware worked smoothly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two line answer: For wired connections it will work smoothly, for wireless turn on 'Promiscious mode' if your wireless adapter does not support promiscious mode, here is the [link](https://www.revolutionweb.com.au/computer-security/use-wireless-adapter-virtualbox-bridge-mode/) to workaround. Also visit offical oracle virtualbox documentation to see more details [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#network_bridged) on using bridged connection over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I uninstall the VirtaulBox, and install by click on the ***VirtualBox*** and ***run as administrator***. After the installation, you can observe that the Bridge Network and USB connections both will be working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am reporting my findings. To make Bridged Adapter work with a *Windows Guest* I have to indicate the device that I am actually connected to in the *Host machine*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Me:
. uninstall existence virtualbox
. install latest virtualbox version
Not work:
. run installer
. choose repair
Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling or Repairing Virtualbox solved my problem too.

Answer (score -2):

**WINDOWS FIX: Ive' Fixed it by downloading a new VMbox installer from the Official Website [Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).**

- Just run the installer and install it to override your current VMBox version,
  that should fix it.

Dont worry about your VM's they will not disappear if you override your current installation.

NOTE: If you already have the latest version, you need to export all your VM's, unninstall your current VMBox and install it from new installer.