# port forwarding to a virtual machine using Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I want to forward a port to a VM. However i dont want the VM to be behind my host PC, i want it to be connected directly to the router so that packets coming on that port go directly to the VM without passing through my host PC.
In other words, i want the VM to look like any other machine on the network. 
EDIT: i used bridged adapter, but i couldnt make it connect to the network.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM will use the Ethernet port in all cases and the OS in it.
Typically if you have Windows and a VM with a bridged port, you will see the traffic flow when you take a capture on the Windows machine. IP won't be the one from the Windows machine but the traffic, like said, will flow through the same physical interface.

Secondly, you need to use a bridged adapter. For the details you can find help here: [Bridged networking not working in Virtualbox under Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922055/bridged-networking-not-working-in-virtualbox-under-windows-10)